# object as method parameter in native C

Tags: c++-cli, native

I need to call the method which includes object of another class in native C.
Below is the code
In Wrapper.h,

```
 class  __declspec(dllexport)UnmanagedAlgebraComputation
 {
   public:
    UnmanagedAlgebraComputation()
        {
           Resolve();
       };

       int AddSubtractMultiplyWrapper(int a,int b);
       int SubtractMultiplyWrapper(UnmanagedSubtraction *unmanagedSubtraction);
       char* DisplayMessageWrapper(char* message);
       void SetHandle(HWND handle);

   private:
       void Resolve();
  /* UnmanagedSubtraction unmanagedSubtraction  =new UnmanagedSubtraction();*/
 };

 class __declspec(dllexport)UnmanagedSubtraction
 {
   public:
       int SubtractMultiply(int a,int b);
   private :
       void Resolve();
 };
```

Here in this statement  SubtractMultiplyWrapper(UnmanagedSubtraction *unmanagedSubtraction); it throws the error as Syntax Error identifier UnmanagedSubtraction. Please let me why it throws the error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the class `UnmanagedSubstraction` before `UnmanagedAlgebraComputation` and it might be fine.